# How to remove the gap between two components in JDialog

Tags: java, jpanel, jdialog

I have following(snippet) JDialog box with gridbag and having multiple components in it. [image]

I want to remove the gap between the "search" textfield and the bottom Jlist. How to do that?

My code snippet is

```
textField_1 = new JTextField(TEXTFIELD_INPUT_PROMPT);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
     gbc_textField_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_textField_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_textField_1.gridx = 6;
    gbc_textField_1.gridy = 5;
    getContentPane().add(textField_1, gbc_textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener(textField_1));

    DefaultListModel<String> model_list = new DefaultListModel<>();
    list = new JList<String>(model_list);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
     gbc_list.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_list.gridx = 2;
    gbc_list.gridy = 6;
    sp = new JScrollPane(list);
    getContentPane().add(sp, gbc_list);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    list.setFixedCellWidth(14);
```

Comment: Anyone,,,,,,,,,,,?

Comment: `GridBagLayout` by default will layout the components with 0 spacing.  You can affect the padding by using things like the `insets` of the `GridBagConstraints` or using different `Border`s on the components. But since you've neglected to provide any kind of code example as to how you're producing this output, it's really impossible to provide a concert suggestion